# how to reflect changes made in a java file while running it?

Tags: java, swing, windows-7

System specifications : Win7 
- Executing through command prompt
- Initially , only 1 button i had created and it could be seen successfully.
- I just added button2 to my code and not able to see it while running this app.

Here's the code of the app :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;


public class Calculatorr extends JFrame{
    JTextField area1=new JTextField();  
    JTextField area2=new JTextField();
    JTextField area3=new JTextField();


    public static void main(String args[])
        {
            new Calculatorr();
        }

        public Calculatorr() 
        {   super("Calc1");
            JFrame jf=new JFrame("Calculatorr");
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            Container content = getContentPane();
            content.setBackground(Color.white);
                content.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,4));

            JButton button1=new JButton("+");
            JButton button2=new JButton("-");   



            JLabel label1 =new JLabel("First number");
            JLabel label2 =new JLabel("Second number");
            JLabel label3 =new JLabel("Result");



            content.add(button2);
            content.add(label1);
            content.add(area1);
            content.add(label2);
            content.add(area2);
            content.add(label3);
            content.add(area3);
            content.add(button1);


            pack();
            setSize(500,500);
            setVisible(true);
        }



}
```

So can anybody suggest as to how do I get to see changes made to be reflected on running this app ?

Comment: `button2` appears in the top-left corner of the grid.

Comment: Maybe you should use java debugger.

Comment: what is the path to where your code is kept and what tool are you editing it with? Are you working directly under Program Files or the root of C:?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're talking about making changes to your source code and having it immediately show up.

Not going to happen. Source code is compiled and then executed. You need to re-run the application.

Comment: I couldn't see any effect in the app after the changes done in the source code on recompiling and re-running it . That is actually my problem !!

Comment: How are you compiling / running it?

Comment: compiling by javac Calculatorr.java and for running : java Calculatorr

Comment: It can and *does* happen -- see [JRebel (formerly Java Rebel)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JRebel) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your title is not clear but if you want to see the second button then you should put the following line:

> content.add(button2);

after

> content.add(button1);

Comment: Ok , I tried that too , but it still doesn't work , I mean button2 is still not visible on recompiling and re-ruuning it

Comment: @user758016 : I was able to run it and see both buttons what version of Java are you using ?

Comment: Interesting have you consider changing the layout ?

Comment: @Amine I have tried changing the layout size values , they also aren't seen on rerunning the app

Comment: what development environment are you using ? Eclipse ?

Comment: try to delete .class file and then recompile the file. (javac myfile.java) then  to execute java myfile...

Comment: Are you able to change the labels (ie "First Number" for "bla bla bla") ?

Comment: well you should reinstall the jsdk but before that you should try restarting your computer and trying ....

Comment: @Amine  yeah on restart , the changes were seen in the app , thanks. Means for every change to be effective I need to restart ??

Comment: Well i do not consider restarting as a valid or acceptable solution !!! you should consider reinstalling Java sdk if you are supposed to restart after each change ....